# Let $x$ be an element of real numbers such that $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$. How do I prove this is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $x$ be an element of real numbers such that $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$. How do I prove this is a group?

Is the question incomplete? We were only taught that we should have a given operation (e.g. multiplication, addition).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What should be a group? The interval $[0,x]$?

Comment: Without an operation it can't be a group.  You'll need to be careful because with addition your set isn't closed (e.g. 2/3 + 2/3 > 1) and you lack inverses (negative numbers)... and with multiplication you'll need to exclude the 0 element since it isn't invertible.

Answer (score 1):

The real interval $[0,1]$ is not a group under multiplication, because taking $1$ as the neutral element, $0$ does not have an inverse.

It is also not a group under addition. Can you see why it is not closed under addition?

So yes, you should ask for clarification on the group operation.